# What is the mass of the Cabin Air Rack of the Quest Joint Airlock?

Tags: life-support, airlock, quest-joint-airlock

And where should I have looked for this information?

The mass of the avionics rack would also be nice.

Comment: I suspect you will be wading into the waters of proprietary or export controlled information if you want rack-level mass properties details.  I will tell you that it is known, and for those who have access, it is fairly easy to find, but I do not believe there has been any public release of that information.  If you want this information to be authoritatively released and made available to the public, your best bet would probably be to contact the Public Affairs Office of the Johnson Space Center.

Comment: That's a bit disappointing. I found the [SPCE mass values](http://spacecraft.ssl.umd.edu/design_lib/ICES02-2366.airlock.pdf) (or at least upper bounds on them) without too much trouble. There's no similar document for the racks?

I'll contact the public affairs office but I'm not sure they'll move before my deadline.

Thanks

Comment: As a note: they may well be perfectly willing to release that information.  A large amount of information doesn't get released not because it explicitly cannot be, but rather because clearing it for release is work that costs money. As an agency with limited resources, they will understandably be choosy with what information the unilaterally release (i.e., without being asked for the information), not out of secrecy, but out of a perception that not enough people would want that information.  Just asking may be enough to get that ball rolling. They tend to be pretty helpful from my experience.